# How to set multiple classes to an element with a conditional

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

This EJS scriptlet

```
<li class=<%= (path==='about') ? 'active main-header--nav-item' : 'main-header--nav-item' %>>about</li>
```

renders on the page as this:

```
<li class="active" main-header--nav-item="">about</li>
```

when I'm trying to make it output as:

```
<li class="active main-header--nav-item">about</li>
```

i.e. two classes. I'm assuming I'm making a simple error with syntax in the conditional but I can't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in your EJS template you are not enclosing the class list with `""`. When that is the case, a whitespace character will end up being interpreted as the end of the attribute. Your template above actually renders into this:

```
<li class=active main-header--nav-item>about</li>
```

The browser will then interpret the `class` to have the value of `active`, and that `main-header--nav-item` is just some custom HTML attribute, hence your observed output of:

```
<li class="active" main-header--nav-item="">about</li>
```

You should be doing this instead:

```
<li class="<%= (path==='about') ? 'active main-header--nav-item' : 'main-header--nav-item' %>">about</li>
```